# CSS3 radial gradient displaying different in different browsers

Tags: css, cross-browser, radial-gradients

I'm trying to use a radial gradient background for my website, it displays alright in Firefox but it displays differently in Chrome and IE. Anyway below is how it looks in Firefox (what I want it too look like) and how it looks for IE and Chrome. I used the [Ultimate CSS gradient generator](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/) to try and maintain cross-browser compatibility. This is the code I'm using for the gradient.

```
background: #0e0e0e; /* No gradient support */
background: -moz-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover,  rgba(234,211,0,0.6) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(radial, center center, 0px, center center, 100%, color-stop(0%,rgba(234,211,0,0.6)), color-stop(100%,rgba(255,255,255,0))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover,  rgba(234,211,0,0.6) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover,  rgba(234,211,0,0.6) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%); /* Opera 12+ */
background: -ms-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover,  rgba(234,211,0,0.6) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center,  rgba(234,211,0,0.6) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ead300', endColorstr='#00ffffff',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-9 fallback on horizontal gradient */
```

Below is the result in different browsers:

[image: Firefox]

Firefox

[image: Chrome and IE]

Chrome and IE

Does anyone know of any solutions to make it look similar in Chrome and IE?

Comment: I think they display differently because the browsers are different as well.What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought: can you just change the -moz first color value's color stop position to make it stronger yellow at the center?

background: -moz-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover,  rgba(234,211,0,0.6) 25%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */

Comment: No, it doesn't have any effect in either browser

Comment: Hi Harry12345.  I don't have Firefox, so I can't test this.  But, I thought of another idea (an obvious one, but an idea nonetheless):
background: -moz-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, rgba(234,211,0,0.6) 0%, rgba(234,211,0,0.6) 25%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */

I just add another color stop so that from 0% to 25% it's pure yellow, and then it tapers out.  I'd love to know if it works...

Answer (score 0):

This is probably due to the way each browser renders the gradient you're using.

I think giving different gradient rules for each vendor prefix would do it.